# MSBuild and MSTest in non-TFS Build tool with MSBuild Outdir

Tags: msbuild, mstest

I've been charged with coming up with a workflow in a non-TFS build tool that will build a solution, run unit test projects in the solution, then package the final output of the build for deployment. I originally had constructed a workflow that used MSBuild with the Outdir parameter to get the publishable application for later storage. When I added unit test projects to the solution they work fine in Visual Studio (2010) but when I run my solution through MSBuild the MSTest step can't find the tests because the VSMDI file points to the BIN folders in the test projects, but the Outdir parameter is applied a the Solution level so the test DLLs are constructed in the Outdir directory instead of the BIN folder. If I remove Outdir from MSBuild the tests run, but I don't get a publishable application. This is a problem for web applications where we don't want to publish the code files and other artifacts that Visual Studio Publish would exclude.

Any ideas how to get MSTest to run the tests correctly based on the VSMDI file when MSBuild is run with Outdir? I thought about scripting an XML transform to change the paths in VSMDI to the Publish folder, but that seems like a hack.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could abandon the vsmdi file all together and pass the dlls in a  list to the commandline tool?
Otherwise id plum for the transform. The transform is not as bad hack as you think because at least you know the devs are running the same tests as your build and you'd have this problem as it occurs when you try to build, test and package the release version.

Comment: I had originally specified a list of the DLLs, but I'm trying to build a "black box" job in AntHillPro that will build and test any Solution so I can't hard-code the test DLLs. I guess I'm going to have to look at a transform. It isn't that big a hack (change "debug\bin\" to my publish folder) but I was hoping there was something I'd missed.